Problema con transacciones que no hacen rollback
tengo un problema relacionado a unas inserciones que estoy haciendo en Spring a una base de datos, donde estoy realizando pruebas (estoy evaluando situaciones hipotéticas), y se me presento esta situación:
Tengo estas 2 entidades:
La entidad Activity
@Entity
@Table(name = GlobalVariables.activityTable, schema = GlobalVariables.schemaMain)
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "START")
    private LocalDate start_date;

    @Column(name = "FINISH")
    private LocalDate finish_date;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SubactivityOfActivity> subactivities;
}

La entidad Subactivity of Activities
@Entity
@Table(name = GlobalVariables.subactivityOfActivityTable, schema = GlobalVariables.schemaMain)
public class SubactivityOfActivity {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "bigint")
private Long id;

@ToString.Exclude
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ACTIVID")
private Activity activity;

@ToString.Exclude
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_SUBACT")
private Subactivity subactivity;

@Column(name = "START")
private LocalDate start_date;

@Column(name = "FINISH")
private LocalDate finish_date;

}
y quiero hacer una inserción de varios registros en distintas tablas:
{
"id": 18,
"name": "Actividad de prueba",
"start_date": "2024-10-10",
"finish_date": "2024-10-10",
"subactivities": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "subactivity": {
            "id": 1
        },
        "start_date": "2024-10-10",
        "finish_date": "2024-10-10"
        }
    ]   
}

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con respecto a si genero el id desde backend y en un caso hipotético se pueda generar una colisión, donde el registro el válido, pero la generarse el id, choca con una existente, en ese caso quiero hacer rollback y notificar al usuario que reintente o generar un procedimiento de reintento en el código (aún no sé que hacer exactamente), pero me pasa algo al hacer persist:
Servicio de Spring:
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void save(Activity activity) throws Exception {
    try {
        activityRepository.saveActivity(activity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("Excepción lanzada");
    }
}

Repositorio de Spring:
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveActivity(Activity activity) {
    System.out.println("Inicio de persistencia");
    em.persist(activity);
    System.out.println("Fin de persistencia");
}

En el caso donde se genera una id válida para la actividad, pero se genera una id duplicada en las subactividades, inserta la actividad, lanza excepción al momento de insertar las subactividades y no hace rollback
Excepciones del servidor:

[2024-10-31T10:41:02.974-0400] [Payara 5.194] [WARNING] []
[javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid:
_ThreadID=33 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1730385662974] [levelValue: 900] [[   DTX5014: Caught
exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
execute batch
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
not execute batch
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [SQL0803] Duplicate key
value specified.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
[SQL0803] Duplicate key value specified.

Excepción que atrapa mi manejador global y me devuelve:

"exception":
"org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException",
"message": "JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a
timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException:
Transaction marked for rollback."

y si, estoy usando los métodos de batch de hibernate en Spring, pero hasta sin batch, me dan los mismos errores, solo puedo suponer que se debe a que ocurre el error al momento de hacer commit implicitamente, por lo tanto no es posible el rollback, pero ¿no hay una forma de fragmentar la transacción? para que la transacción principal al detectar la excepción conserve el punto de guardado y sea capaz de hacer rollback? ¿o hay alguna manera de atrapar esa excepción y para que si haga rollback?
